# How to set indeterminate state in vuetify checkbox?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a checkbox in Vuetify and at first it has an indeterminate state. After I change it to true or false, I have a button to reset it to default and show the indeterminate state again but it doesnt work. What's wrong?
the defalut value for indeterminate is true and value is null.

```
<v-checkbox
  :indeterminate="indeterminate"
  v-model="value"
></v-checkbox>
```

and the button does this:

```
<v-btn @click="setToDefault()"> set to default </v-btn>
```

method:

```
    setToDefault(){
      this.value = null
      this.indeterminate = true
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component listen for the changes and sets itself to an `indeterminate` state when the value changes to `false` to `true`. So, to accomplish that you need to set the value `indeterminate` to `false` whenever the v-model value of the checkbox changes. You can do that by listening to `value`

```
<v-checkbox
  :indeterminate="indeterminate"
   v-model="value"
   label="My Checkbox"
></v-checkbox>
<v-btn @click="setToDefault()"> set to default </v-btn>

export default {
  data: {
    value: null,
    indeterminate: false
  },
  watch: {
     value(){
       this.indeterminate = false
     }
  },
  methods: {
    setToDefault(){
      // Also, below line should be removed.
      // this.value = false
      this.indeterminate = true
     }
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/aaha/pen/NWGBMmZ?editors=1011